# How to capitalize first letter of a user name which has two names in the first name? in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a first name such as "**mike martin**" and last name as "**robert john**"
I have used the ucfirst function, it is working, but, it only converts like **"Mike martin"** 
I want those 2 names in the first name to be like **Mike Martin**

How can i do that? is there any other function to capitalize each and every first letter of a name which has 2 parts?

Comment: What does this have to do with Javascript, or HTML, or CSS? Please only tag your questions with tags that are *relevant*

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Maybe it's easier to convert from there? Just a thought..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **ucwords()**

```
ucwords("mike martin");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
echo ucwords("mike martin");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used **ucfirst()** ,
Use **ucwords()**
as

```
 ucwords('mike martin');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ucwords` and `strtolower`. Like this:-

```
echo ucwords(strtolower('Mike martin'));
```